# How can I get this type of menu?

Tags: 7, navigation

I want to get a menu similar to the one shown on net.cn; under the logo there is a navigation bar with 6 menu items; when you hover the mouse over one of the menu items, the bar under it shows the child menu items.

[image: screenshot]

Is there a module to obtain something similar? Which code can I use to obtain the same effect?